# Storage transfer job from one google cloud storage region to another with Python "Failed to rewrite object."

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to run a storage transfer job to copy  files from a starting location bucket to a bucket in a destination location.

The following code fails to rewrite starting bucket files to destination bucket.

```
import datetime
import sys
import time

import googleapiclient.discovery
from google.cloud import bigquery, storage
import json
import pytz


PROJECT_ID = 'myproject_id'  # TODO: set this to your project name

FROM_BUCKET = 'source_bucket'  

TO_BUCKET = 'destination_bucket'  
# Construct API clients.
bq_client = bigquery.Client(project=PROJECT_ID)
transfer_client = googleapiclient.discovery.build('storagetransfer', 'v1')

def transfer_buckets():
# Transfer files from one region to another using storage transfer service.
print('Transferring bucket {} to {}'.format(FROM_BUCKET, TO_BUCKET))
now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
transfer_job = {
    'description': '{}-{}-{}_once'.format(
        PROJECT_ID, FROM_BUCKET, TO_BUCKET),
    'status': 'ENABLED',
    'projectId': PROJECT_ID,
    'transferSpec': {
        'transferOptions': {
            'overwriteObjectsAlreadyExistingInSink': True,
        },
        'gcsDataSource': {
            'bucketName': FROM_BUCKET,
        },
        'gcsDataSink': {
            'bucketName': TO_BUCKET,
        },
    },
    # Set start and end date to today (UTC) without a time part to start
    # the job immediately.
    'schedule': {
        'scheduleStartDate': {
            'year': now.year,
            'month': now.month,
            'day': now.day,
        },
        'scheduleEndDate': {
            'year': now.year,
            'month': now.month,
            'day': now.day,
        },
    },
}
transfer_job = transfer_client.transferJobs().create(
    body=transfer_job).execute()
print('Returned transferJob: {}'.format(
    json.dumps(transfer_job, indent=4)))

# Find the operation created for the job.
job_filter = {
    'project_id': PROJECT_ID,
    'job_names': [transfer_job['name']],
}

# Wait until the operation has started.
response = {}
while ('operations' not in response) or (not response['operations']):
    time.sleep(1)
    response = transfer_client.transferOperations().list(
        name='transferOperations', filter=json.dumps(job_filter)).execute()

operation = response['operations'][0]
print('Returned transferOperation: {}'.format(
    json.dumps(operation, indent=4)))

# Wait for the transfer to complete.
print('Waiting ', end='')
while operation['metadata']['status'] == 'IN_PROGRESS':
    print('.', end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(5)
    operation = transfer_client.transferOperations().get(
        name=operation['name']).execute()
print()

print('Finished transferOperation: {}'.format(
    json.dumps(operation, indent=4)))
```

I call the transfer with:

```
transfer_buckets()
```

Error description:

```
Finished transferOperation: {
"name": "transferOperations/transferJobs-11674570151123793778-1526499677451343",
"response": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Empty"
},
"metadata": {
    "transferJobName": "transferJobs/11674570151123793778",
    "status": "FAILED",
    "name": "transferOperations/transferJobs-11674570151123793778-1526499677451343",
    "startTime": "2018-05-16T19:41:17.495502150Z",
    "errorBreakdowns": [
        {
            "errorCode": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
            "errorCount": "4",
            "errorLogEntries": [
                {
                    "url": "gs://source_bucket/file1",
                    "errorDetails": [
                        "Failed to rewrite object."
                    ]
                },

    ...
```

The underlying service account used for the transfer operation is granted with read and write access to existing buckets with object listing/creation/deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appears because the two buckets are in different locations.

Trying to replicate the action by moving the files directly in google storage, I have encountered the following error.

```
You must use gsutil for this move. This is because the destination uses a different storage class or location from the source.
```

A work around for this will be calling gsutil in the python script.

```
import os

os.system('gsutil mv gs://source_bucket/file1 gs://destination_bucket')

os.system('gsutil rm -r gs://source_bucket/file1')
```

Comment: I believe this is incorrect. Storage Transfer Service is able to copy between regions. Based on the error message, perhaps you need to set overwriteObjectsAlreadyExistingInSink to true https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/reference/rest/v1/TransferSpec#TransferOptions

Comment: I have this option set already:                                      `'transferOptions': {
            'overwriteObjectsAlreadyExistingInSink': True,
 }`